# Overriding CSS for rendered MDBootrap elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mdbootstrap

I am using MDBoostrap (similar to Bootstrap) for styling my elements in a React app. Now I have a select element which is written like as shown below.

```
<div>
    <select id="Regions" style={errorSelect} value={this.state.userRegionId} onChange={this.handleRegionChange}>
      {this.handleGetRegions()}
    </select>
</div>
```

When it renders, it generates some HTML like this.
[image]

I tried doing something like this.

```
//...
const errorSelect = {
  borderBottom: '2px solid #FF0000'
};
//...
<select id="Regions" className={errorSelect} value={this.state.userRegionId} onChange={this.handleRegionChange}>
  {this.handleGetRegions()}
</select>
//...
```

As you can see, even if I apply `className` or `style` element in my React code, it won't affect since the main UI gets rendered/translated to `input` and `ul` elements. Any idea on how I can apply my own CSS by overriding (or adding an extra style) to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can force your own css with adding "  !important " a the end of the line of css.
And your own css file must be import after the css file of MDBootstrap.
Hope I help.

Comment: It won't work because the elements after being rendered are not the `select` but `input` and `ul` elements, which gets transformed by the MDBootstrap. I have already explained this above.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override MDB CSS classes such as `select-options-wrapper`, `select-option`, and `select-option-group`. However, if you do override them, they will be overridden for all instances of select as there does not seem to be any easy way to target specific instances.